# Better forums for questions not appropriate for InfoSec StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I realize this question may be outside terms of appropriate questions -- is somewhat subjective or non-specific -- however the purpose of the question is to point me (and others) to more appropriate resources for just such questions.

Some questions I've posted have been well-received and given informative, helpful answers. Other less specific, or less fact-based questions I initially tacked on to the more "legit" questions, and then took others' suggestions to break these off into their own questions, which predictably were closed as invalid for the forum.

In between the fact-based and the opinion-based are things I might categorize as "newbie" -- things that are valid technical questions pertaining to security, but which might be rejected as too basic, or perhaps seen as bordering on technical support. For instance (examples only, not actually asking these here):

- Analysis of system logs where some entries are suspicious to an untrained eye, and actual suspect entries (to someone more experienced) may not occur to the questioner. Posting a gist to ask, does anyone see cause for alarm given possible threat X? Maybe sometimes this is legit, but other times might be asking for help in a too broad hunt.
- Questions about making sense of traffic with wireshark or netstat, or even strategies for digging through noisy data. (Or for that matter, help with these tools that seems to not be clearly explained in the man pages.) RTFM is good idea, but it doesn't answer everything and as is often true of manuals, can provide too much info to wade through for someone new to using the tool.
- Questions about exploit vectors, their prevalence in the wild, and when greater security would apply for a specific type of attack (as in, when the target is more valued than random attacks).
- Broad questions that are by nature somewhat subjective, like which browsers are safer against certain types of threats.

I imagine some or all of these being not appropriate for the InfoSec StackExchange, so would like to know where else I might get community answers, or how I might better frame these as appropriate questions.

Hope this question will not be immediately closed! I realize I could go to some meta site, but am preferring to ask the regulars here first. Thanks. (Tagging as cybersecurity because that term seems sufficiently meaningless as to cover my broad question.)

Comment: It probably will actually. The reason it's on the wrong site. This should be on Meta rather than here. You are correct that some of these questions are off-topic, but not all. 1,2 and 3 are perfectly on topic as long as the OP shows he has put effort in trying to solve the issue at hand himself. But we do reject "can you work for free for me" questions.

Comment: @LucasKauffman,  Iquestions of type 1 don't seem like a great fit to me (posting a dump of a log and asking if it shows evidence of problems doesn't sound likely to be helpful to other users).  I agree that questions of type 2 and 3 seem perfectly on topic as long as the author has done enough research, as Lucas says.  Unfortunately, I don't have any recommendations for better forums for the questions that are off-topic.